# SharePoint presentation(PPT)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I need a presentation of SharePoint on PowerPoint (marketing documentation).

It may be a Standard or personalized.

**Note**: If it's in french it will be better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My email is adel.ouici@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You can download SharePoint 2013: Presentation: IT pro training from the following URL:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30361